# Return struct in class template function

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, struct

I'm learning C++ with some exercises from a book that I found a while ago. My task is described below and I've tried to find a work around for returning a template node I created for the template function `getLastNode` to add a node at the end of the list. Is it possible to do that, currently I can't find a way to let's call it explain the compiler what TNode is as a struct within a class return value.

I might have the best way to declare nodes in this code. Perhaps, a struct within a class can complicate class template methods implementations. Do you feel there's another strategy? Please let me know

Cheers!

```cpp
/* Implement the data structure dynamic doubly linked list (DoublyLinkedList<T>) - list,
 * the elements of which have pointers both to the next and the previous elements. Implement 
 * the operations for adding, removing and searching for an element, as well as inserting
 * an element at a given index, retrieving an element by a given index and a method, which returns an array with the elements of the list*/

#include <iostream>

template<typename TValue>
class List{
  struct TNode{
    TValue value;
    TNode *previous;
    TNode *next;
  }Node;
  public:

    List();
    ~List();
    void addNode(TValue); 
  private:
    TNode *root;
    TNode getLastNode(TNode);
};

template<typename TValue>
List<TValue>::List():root(0) {}

template<typename TValue>
List<TValue>::~List<TValue>(){
}

template<typename TValue>
TNode List<TValue>::getLastNode(TNode node){
  if(node.next==nullptr) 
    return node;
  else
   getLastNode(node.next);
}

template<typename TValue>
void List<TValue>::addNode(TValue value){
  const TNode last = getLastNode(root);
  last.next = Node;
  last.next->value = value;
}

int main(){
  List<int> test;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `List<TValue>::TNode List<TValue>::getLastNode(TNode node){` or `auto List<TValue>::getLastNode(TNode node) -> TNode` or just `auto List<TValue>::getLastNode(TNode node){`

Comment: *"I can't find a way to let's call it explain the compiler what TNode is as a struct within a class return value."* -- huh?

Comment: `typename List<TValue>::TNode` don't ignore the leading `typename`

Comment: Hi @yeputons thanks for your help. I tried all of you suggestion but none of them worked. the one that threw the fewest compiler error was auto `Extra qualification on member 'getLastNode' inside the private attributes of the class.

Comment: Hi @JaMiT, yeah that was bad English. What I meant is that I'd not found a well to tell the compiler the return type for that function.

Comment: Hey @Nimrod. Thanks for your suggestion, I'm not a profecient c++ user, could your elaborate your suggestion please?

Comment: @JuanJáuregui *"What I meant is that I'd not found a well to tell the compiler the return type for that function."* -- could you find a way to tell **us** what the return type of the function is supposed to be? Because if I have to go off the code, I see that you told the compiler that the return type of `getLastNode` is `TNode`, so what's the problem? (If it's a syntax error, the error message should be copied into the question.)

Comment: @JaMiT I put an unnecessary `List<TValue>::TNode` in my function declaration inside my class, my bad ;) I'll post your suggestion with `auto` as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To return `TNode` for the `getLastNode` method I had to add `auto` to its class method declaration.

Credits: @JaMiT

```
template<typename TValue>
auto List<TValue>::getLastNode(TNode node){
  if(node.next==nullptr)
    return node;
  else
    getLastNode(node.next);
}
```